# How can I cash a US Bank check outside of the United States?

Tags: united-states, banking, check

My account in the US Bank is closed and they have sent a check to me.  Since I am out of the U.S., now in the middle east, how can I cash the check?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you will find anyone to give you cash for it. Your own bank should allow you to deposit it, though it may take several weeks to clear.

Answer (score 2):

Surprising enough, I learned that many banks in Europe accept US dollar personal checks etc., for deposit in your account. I would assume that this is similar in the Middle East.
You need to have an account for that, obviously, and several days of time.

As an alternative, you can try to find a local branch office of a US bank, like Chase or City Bank; if they exist where you live, they might be able to cash the check (it will take some days too, for sure).

Note that either way, there will be a significant fee, and if your check has less than three digits, you are probably better off throwing it in the trash.

Comment: thank you guys,Unfortunately, the US bank do NOT have branches overseas as i told by them , since I do have CHASE account as well, and regarding European banks, I dont have account there and not sure they have any policy for foreigner to be able to open one ?